# Eclipse "Go Into" with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In Eclipse if you right-click on a project folder, you have the option to "Go Into".  Is there something similar in IntelliJ?

In large projects it can be useful to narrow your working space down to a single module or directory.

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, although you can create views, iirc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest option is to use the "Add to Favorites" action to add a module or directory to a favorites list. Then the Favorites list will show only that module/directory and its children.

Another option is to set up a scope in Settings | Appearance and Behavior | Scopes and to switch to the view of that scope in the Project view. This is more difficult to set up than Favorites, but also more flexible and less cluttered.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  "Add to Favorites" was what I was looking for.   Unfortunately it only works well when you have a single directory that you'd like to isolate, because once you start adding more favorites, it becomes its own cluttered mess.